# OpenCV Hierarchy is always null

Tags: java, opencv, hierarchy

I have an image with overlapping contours and I have been trying to filter out the contours using hierarchy when I find them. What I am trying to do is filter out contours whose parents aren't equal to -1. However, when I try to get the information containing hierarchy the parent index is almost every time equal to null. Am I not looking at the right information for the getting the status of the current contours parent? Here is my code.

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MatOfPoint> squareContours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    //find all contours
    Imgproc.findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    //Remove contours that aren't close to a square shape.
    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        if(hierarchy != null){
            double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)); 
            MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
            double perimeter = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true);
            //Found squareness equation on wiki... 
            //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)
            double squareness = 4 * Math.PI * area / Math.pow(perimeter, 2);

            if(squareness >= 0.7 && squareness <= 0.9 && area >= 2000){
                squareContours.add(contours.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    //remove contour if it has a parent 
    List<MatOfPoint> finalContours = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < squareContours.size();i++){
        if(hierarchy.get(i, 3)[3] == -1){ //this should be checking parent index I think.
            finalContours.add(squareContours.get(i));
        }
    }
```

This is the output of the program when I print the hierarchy matrix that contains the parent information `Arrays.toString(hierarchy.get(i,3)))`

```
[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 2.0]
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: What is the actual shape and datatype of `hierarchy` after the call to `findContours`? Print it out or inspect it in debugger. | The `3` as a column number in the `get` seems a little suspect.

Comment: The shape of the contours are square. Hierarchy is a Mat @DanMašek

Comment: No, I mean how many rows, columns, and channels it has, and what is the type of each element (uint8, float, etc.). | In C++ I never passed a `Mat` there, so I'm not sure... let me try that.

Comment: The type is CvType is Cv8U and each element is an int. In an array like a Mat would be @DanMašek

Comment: I know what a `Mat` is, I was asking for the specific 3 numbers. But never mind, I've already done some tests.

Comment: Just to explain -- I wrote some simple code in C++ that used `Mat` to store the hierarchy, then set a breakpoint right after the `findContours` call, and then looked at the `hierarchy` variable in the debugger -- there I could see the size (number of rows and columns) and data type of the elements along with the number of channels. Then some perusal of the OpenCV java documenation. You ought to be able to do something like that with Java too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a `Mat` to represent the hierarchy returned by `findContours`, you get an array which contains:

- a single row
- a column per detected contour
- 4 channels (id of next, previous, child, and parent contour)
- data type a 32bit signed integer

Now, your problem becomes immediately evident.

```
hierarchy.get(i, 3)[3]
```

The [`get`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#get(int,%20int)) method you use has the following signature:

```
public double[] get(int row, int col)
```

Notice that the first parameter is the row number. You pass the contour number as row, but there is only a single row.

Next, the second parameter is the column. You always get column 3 -- the hierarchy info for the 3rd contour.

What you really ought to be doing is something like

```
hierarchy.get(0, i)[3]
```

The final issue is that you're unnecessarily converting the indices to floating point numbers. This is wasteful, and counterproductive, since to be of much use you'd have to convert them back to ints. Just use an [appropriate overload of `get`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#get(int,%20int,%20int[])).

Now, my Java is rusty, but I think you could do something like this:

```
int[] current_hierarchy = new int[4];
for(int i = 0; i < squareContours.size();i++) {
    hierarchy.get(0, i, current_hierarchy);
    if (current_hierarchy[3] == -1) {
        // ... and so on
```

---

There's another problem I notice. After the call to `findContours`, the values in `hierarchy` correspond to the indices (positions) in the `contours` list. However, you first remove some contours (by inserting only a subset of them into another list), without any similar changes to the hierarchy data. Then you iterate over this subset, and end up using wrong hierarchy entries due to mismatching indices.

To solve this, I'd merge the two loops together, perhaps like this:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
//find all contours
Imgproc.findContours(dilated, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// Remove contours that aren't close to a square shape
// and remove contour if it has a parent 
List<MatOfPoint> finalContours = new ArrayList<>();
int[] current_hierarchy = new int[4];
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)); 
    MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
    double perimeter = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true);
    //Found squareness equation on wiki... 
    //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)
    double squareness = 4 * Math.PI * area / Math.pow(perimeter, 2);

    if(squareness >= 0.7 && squareness <= 0.9 && area >= 2000){
        hierarchy.get(0, i, current_hierarchy);
        if (current_hierarchy[3] == -1) {
            finalContours.add(contours.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks :). So all in all I should just use a version of get to find the parent hierarchy or are you talking about the MatOfPoint stuff?

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber See the edit. It's not essential, just avoids multiple allocations of those arrays, and the conversions between int and double.

Comment: Alright, I see it but could I add more to the question because it is working but I am getting a different result than I expected. Maybe it will clarify better.

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Ok, add it as an update to the bottom of your question. | Actually I think I see what the problem is :) The position in the hierarchy corresponds to the position in the original list of contours. Since `squareContours` is a subset of all the found contours, the indices will no longer match.

Comment: Updated it @DanMašek

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Have a look at the update, and see if that solves the problem. It might be yet another issue tho, I've noticed this before your update.

Comment: I just checked and now finalContours only contains 2 contours. It prints the bottom middle and the center one. The rest aren't shown.

Comment: OK, I'm getting a bit tired, and this seems to go a bit further than the original question. Why don't you make a new one, with an [mcve] containing the updated code, and a sample image we can use to reproduce the problem? Also, step through the code in the debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: I will try to see if I can figure out what if not I will post a question with the new code, thanks for all the help :) I really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting item from list of hiearchy, it is needed to also check for relations of deleted item. I first transfer complete hierarchy Mat to List like this:

```
List<double[]> listHierarchy = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
                    listHierarchy.add(hierarchie.get(0, i));
                }
```

Then, when I need to delete item from this list I call this function:

```
 List<double[]> deleteHierarchyItem(int position, List<double[]> hierarchy){
    double[] itemHierarchy = hierarchy.get(position);
    double[] workItem;

    //doesnt have children?
    if (itemHierarchy[2]!=-1){
        int nextChild =(int) (itemHierarchy[2]);
        do {
            //nacte dite
            workItem = hierarchy.get(nextChild);
            //zmeni rodice v diteti na rodice puvodniho rodice
            workItem[3] = itemHierarchy[3];
            //nastavi nova data v listu
            hierarchy.set(nextChild, workItem);
            //zmeni ukazatel na nove dite
            nextChild = (int)(workItem[2]);

        } while (nextChild != -1);
    }

    //check for siblings
    boolean hasNextSibling = itemHierarchy[0] != -1;
    boolean hasPreviousSibling = itemHierarchy[1] != -1;

    double idPreviousSibling = itemHierarchy[1];
    double idNextSibling = itemHierarchy[0];

    //has both siblings
    if (hasPreviousSibling && hasNextSibling){
        //change previous sibling
        workItem = hierarchy.get((int)(idPreviousSibling));
        workItem[0] = idNextSibling;
        hierarchy.set((int)(idPreviousSibling), workItem);
        //change next sibling
        workItem = hierarchy.get((int)(idNextSibling));
        workItem[1] = idPreviousSibling;
        hierarchy.set((int)(idNextSibling), workItem);
    }

    //has only previous sibling
    if (hasPreviousSibling && !hasNextSibling){
        workItem = hierarchy.get((int)(idPreviousSibling));
        workItem[0] = -1;
        hierarchy.set((int)(idPreviousSibling), workItem);
    }

    //has only next sibling
    if (!hasPreviousSibling && hasNextSibling){
        workItem = hierarchy.get((int)(idNextSibling));
        workItem[1] = -1;
        hierarchy.set((int)(idNextSibling), workItem);

        //change of child parametres in parent
        if(itemHierarchy[3]>0)
        {
            workItem = hierarchy.get((int)(itemHierarchy[3]));
            workItem[2]=idNextSibling;
            hierarchy.set((int)(itemHierarchy[3]), workItem);
        }
    }

    //check for parent
    if (itemHierarchy[3]!=-1){
        workItem = hierarchy.get((int)(itemHierarchy[3]));
        if (workItem[2]==position){
            workItem[2] = -1;
            hierarchy.set((int)(itemHierarchy[3]), workItem);
        }
    }

    //iterate and decrement values
    for (int i = position; i< hierarchy.size();i++){
        workItem = hierarchy.get(i);
        if (workItem[0]>position){
            workItem[0] = workItem[0] - 1;
        }
        if (workItem[1]>position){
            workItem[1] = workItem[1] - 1;
        }
        if (workItem[2]>position){
            workItem[2] = workItem[2] - 1;
        }
        if (workItem[3]>position){
            workItem[3] = workItem[3] - 1;
        }
        hierarchy.set(i, workItem);
    }
    return hierarchy;
}
```